# Pandas dataframe column naming

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, ipython

So in ipython i have created a pandas dataset and it is called df1. I cannot change the name of the column my code is:

```
df1=pandas.DataFrame([[2,4,10],[100,200,300],columns=[“Price”,”Age”,”Value”]])
```

And the error is showing syntax error. on the colums equal to sign

Comment: The problem are in `“` characters... use either single or double quotations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need list of lists for `data` parameter and also replace `“` to `'` or `"`:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame(data=[[2,4,10],[100,200,300]],columns=['Price','Age','Value'])
print (df1)    
   Price  Age  Value
0      2    4     10
1    100  200    300
```

---

```
df1=pd.DataFrame(data=[[2,4,10],[100,200,300]],columns=["Price","Age","Value"])
```